# Why does my magnet feel stronger when it is inside it's little metallic cover?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I was recently given a little badge thing to wear to celebrate some event. The badge can be fastened to my shirt using a little magnet. The badge and magnet have since become a little fidget toy for when I am reading something at my desk.

The magnet is composed of 2 parts that (prior to my fidgeting) were glued together: 1) the actual magnet: a flat disc. 2) a sort of metallic cover shaped like a saucer/plate.

When the magnet is in it's cover, there is almost no magnetic force from the back, and from the front, it is quite strong. When the magnet is not in it's cover, the magnet is relatively weak.

It is as if somehow the cover redirects the magnetic force to double it up from the front. What is going on here?